# Largest convex hull of a unit length path

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, calculus-of-variations

What is the largest area possible for the convex hull of a path of unit length lying on a plane? For what paths is that largest area attained?

Comment: By "largest", do you mean largest area?

Comment: Yes, the convex hull having the largest area.

Comment: The same question seems even more intriguing in dimension $3$.

Comment: It may just be an open problem in Dimension 3, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/83026/34859) on MO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer seems to be $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, using a semi circle. See

[Moran, P. A. P. "On a problem of S. Ulam." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 1.3 (1946): 175-179.](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-21/3/175.full.pdf)

Comment: "Seems" seems to be an understatement. Moran also proves that the semicircle is the unique maximizer.

Comment: @Misha Yes. There are many variants of this question, for example taking an circle instead of an interval. See [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2010-362-09/S0002-9947-10-04734-3/) for an overview.