# Trees with a maximal convex hull: are the only optimal solutions Steiner trees?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, trees, extremal-combinatorics

For given $n\geqslant 3$, I'm looking for a connected set composed of $n$ equal segments in the plane such that the convex hull of it has maximal area $A(n)$. To simplify notation, we'll take $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt[4]{3}}$ as the length of each segment, so the unit triangle has area $1$.

It turns out that for small $n$, all the optimal solutions are *Steiner trees*, in the sense that each point belonging to more than one segment is the common endpoint of either two segments forming a straight line, or of three segments forming angles of $\dfrac{2\pi}{{3}}$. We'll call points of the latter kind *branching points*.

Using Steiner trees with only one branching point and the three legs of almost same length, we get the trivial lower bounds
$ \ \ \,\quad A(3k)\geqslant 3k^2$,
$A(3k+1)\geqslant k(3k+2)$,
$A(3k+2)\geqslant (k+1)(3k+1)$.

Equally, we can write $A(n)\geqslant \left[\frac{n^2}3\right]= $ [A000212](http://oeis.org/A000212) $(n)$. The oeis entry contains several interesting comments but nothing which immediately applies here.

For a given $n$, there can be other Steiner trees of same length with more than one branching point which yield the same area. It might be an interesting question how many non-isomorphic ones exist, but before that, I want to ask the following:

> - Is this bound sharp for all $n$?
> - Are there optimal solutions which are *not* Steiner trees?

*(EDIT: in fact, for $n=2,3,4$ taking $n$ consecutive edges of a regular hexagon yields also optimal solutions, which I would however consider marginal.)*
This is somewhat converse to the problem of [Steiner minimal trees for convex polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) but not exactly.

The problem, the above construction and both questions can be immediately generalized to trees spanning volumes in $\mathbb R^d$ instead of $\mathbb R^2$. Conjecturally the answers are the same as for the plane.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, would you be seeking the maximum surface area of the hull, or the maximum volume?

Comment: I automatically thought of the volume. But definitely also a nice idea to wonder about maximizing the surface!

Comment: This may be a distraction, but I wonder if your question could be more easily answered on a lattice? You probably know there is work on lattice Steiner trees, e.g., "[Minimal Steiner Trees for Rectangular Arrays of Lattice Points](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009731659692751X)."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I cannot see how to introduce a lattice. In my setting, all segments composing the tree have the same length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may ask an analogous continuous problem:

> Which connected set composed of simple arcs of total length $1$ has the largest convex hull?

If my computations are correct, the star formed by three segments of length $1/3$ and forming the angles $2\pi/3$ gives a triangle of area $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}} \sim \frac{1}{6.93}$, whereas a half-circle of length $1$ gives a half-disc of area $\frac{1}{2\pi} \sim \frac{1}{6.28}$, which is larger.

This implies that for large enough $n$, the Steiner tree with one branching point is not optimal.

---

**Edit:**
I just found that this problem has been solved in the special case that the connected set is a curve; see the following question:
[Largest convex hull of a unit length path](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141651/largest-convex-hull-of-a-unit-length-path)

The three-dimensional case is discussed here:
[Largest possible volume of the convex hull of a curve of unit length](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83026/largest-possible-volume-of-the-convex-hull-of-a-curve-of-unit-length)

Comment: Great approach and big surprise! It looks like you are right. For $n$ as small as $n=6$, taking half of a 12-gon yields an area $6+4\sqrt{3}\approx 12.93>12$.

Comment: And even for $n=5$, taking 5 sides of an octagon yields an area $2\sqrt{3}(1+\sqrt{2})\approx8.36>8.$

Comment: Thank you also for the two links. After seeing your answer, I realized that this is closely related to those questions about *curves* in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$. How misleading it can be to stick too much to the idea of "trees"!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for posting this potentially
distracting non-answer, but I wanted to illustrate a possibly simpler
problem on a lattice ($n=8$):

---

[image: OrthoTrees]

---

Comment: OK, I see. So in fact you want the whole tree on a lattice. Definitely simpler! But this has nothing to do with the paper linked in your comment above then. (I had desperately tried to make a connection :)

Comment: @Wolfgang: Apologies for that misdirection.

Comment: Definitely simpler. If you move horizontal and vertical lines around (I mean the 'whole' lines), as long as they have a common point, the area doesn't change. So the maximal area here should be $n^2/8$ for n even and $(n^2-1)/8$ for n odd.

Comment: Even though elementary, this is interesting in the light of @Jan Kyncl's answer: for your variant of the problem, the "continuisation" wouldn't give anything. Take a large $n=4r$ and approach a half-circle of radius r by a lattice path. Then we can "bend out" the zigzag parts, maintaining the total length, until arriving at the circumscribed rectangle as hull, again with area $n^2/8$.